# How to uninstall mySIMBLHelper service installed by SIMBL for MAC

Tags: mac, macos, services, sip, simbl

I wanted to install Atop which required SIMBL to be installed.
Nothing at the process stated that SIMBL 0.7.5 wasn't compatible with Mojave 10.14.
It started to pop confirmation if I want it to control xyz application.
I then started to check to uninstall it and loss a lot of time.

The process is commented in here https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL/issues/102
1. Disable SIP:

```
Boot into Recovery mode: Restart and hold cmd+r
In Menu -> Toolings -> Start “Terminal”
$ csrutil disable; reboot
```

2. Run the script and perform uninstallation. It deletes a list of files.
   https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL/issues/102
3. re enable SIP

   same as (1) change to "enable" to re-enable SIP

**THE PROBLEM IS A DAEMON mySIMBLHelper IS NOT UNINSTALLED**

I checked the files that it opens, and there are at least 2 places that are not deleted by the script:

```
"$HOME/Library/Caches/org.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper"
"/private/var/folders/tl/*/T/AppTranslocation/*/d/mySIMBL.app"
```

However the second one, can not be deleted because is a mounted file and it contains a copy of the original mySIMBL.

> I tried restarting in SAFE MODE holding SHIFT at boot to force the
>   flush of temp files but didn't worked.

The to gather more information I got to dump with launchctl

```
launchctl dumpstate > dump.txt
```

It shows up dozens of services with the next line included

```
domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.rg.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper.3734
```

while it also shows that service as well

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.rg.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper.3734 = {
    type = process
    handle = 3734
    active count = 27
    on-demand count = 1
    service count = 26
    active service count = 0
    activity ratio = 0.00
    originator = /private/var/folders/tl/yytk78b9195dbtvrhmhvfn100000gn/T/AppTranslocation/D5C172B8-7F7A-4E7E-B147-18B24DD76FDA/d/mySIMBL.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/mySIMBLHelper.app/Contents/MacOS/mySIMBLHelper
    creator = mySIMBLHelper.3734
    creator euid = 501
    uniqueid = 3734
    external activation count = 0
    security context = {
        uid = 501
        asid = 100064
    }
...
```

**I need help to uninstall it or to stop it from running.**

I can't even find the file where it is fired.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. So I found the way myself.
The next are all the files that need to be added to the script.
I deleted them manually, so I am not sure if it will work without editing.

With this, mySIMBLHelper stoped starting and all the dumpstate shown with by launchctl.
Hope it helps.

```
"$HOME/Library/Caches/org.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper"
"/private/var/folders/tl/*/T/AppTranslocation/*/d/mySIMBL.app"
"/private/var/folders/tl/*/C/org.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper"
"$HOME/Library/Preferences/org.w0lf.mySIMBL.plist"
"$HOME/Library/Preferences/org.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper.plist"
"$HOME/Library/Caches/org.w0lf.mySIMBLHelper"
```

Don't try SIMBL !!

Comment: You can dump the related files via `find / -name *mySIMBL* -print 2>/dev/null` and run `rm -r` for all. To remove the agent use `sudo rm -r "/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/SIMBLAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/SIMBLAgent"`as explained in [GitHub mySIMBL](https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL/issues/104#issuecomment-442834406)

Answer (score 0):

try these commands to completely remove it launchctl list | egrep {SIMBLAgent} and launchctl remove {SIMBLAgent}

Comment: That does not remove it - it might stop it running